# Connect Vue.js and laravel

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js

Greeting developers, I am a university student and really new to using frameworks. Currently, i done one project for my intern using laravel framework for back end. 
Now i plan to do front end using vuejs framework.May i know how to connect the back end and front end. I see previous question in stack overflow there mention can connect using Rest api. May i know how it can happen.Furthermore, i also want to know which is better front end framework for laravel based back end framework angularjs or vuejs.

```
<html>Thanks in advance</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "connect" your app to a backend service (whatever Laravel/Express/RoR etc), you have to make HTTP calls to your backend server.

With VueJS, you can use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make HTTP calls.

Example of usage:

`axios.get('https://yourbackend.io/users/all').then(users => { 
    this.users = users;
 });`

About your last question, there's no "best framework" to use/learn along with any backend technology. However, if you want to see good resources for Laravel and VueJS, you can watch [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/) videos.

Comment: really thank you for your answer. i will try it

Comment: If you need more explanation, don't hesitate to provide more code

Comment: Since Laravel version 5.3, Vue.js has been the default frontend framework included in a Laravel installation. Vue and Laravel offer an immensely powerful and flexible full-stack framework for developing web applications.

Comment: Sure but it doesn't mean that you only have yo use it. But yes I agree this is a popular stack

Comment: @Zooly thanks a lot for your help :)